# Is the projection of a Jordan measurable set Jordan measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

The projection of a Borel set need not be a Borel set, and the projection of a Lebesgue measurable set need not be Lebesgue measurable.  My question is, is the projection of a Jordan measurable set always Jordan measurable?

I expect the answer is no, but are there are any counterexamples to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure#Extension_to_more_complicated_sets), a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is Jordan measurable if and only if its boundary is Lebesgue null. In particular, it must be Lebesgue measurable.

Now take any bounded nonmeasurable subset $V$ of the real line. Then  ${V\times\{0\}}$ is Jordan measurable since its closure has Lebesgue outer measure $0$. But its projection into the first coordinate is not.

Comment: Is the projection of a set with positive Jordan measure always Jordan measurable?

Comment: No. Take the union of the given set and a square sitting beside it.